# Arsenic Based Life

Tags: crosswords

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

**Down**

1 Character in mario whose name does not match his species

2 Sebiora

3 Bread for a panini

4 Impolite way to say woman

5 Between non and sine

6 To be human

7 riiiiip in pieces xxxdddd so done

9 Good puzzles hagee them

10 Vehicle for transporting large things

11 Most emails, probably

13 Vehicle for descending hills

17 Lamcer ray

18 Advertise for your own product

19 Someone with a bad tepper

20 2.75 pounds in turkish

21 One of many ways of saying nonsb

22 Resort for relaxation

23 Help

28 Polite way to say woman

29 UK insult

30 Scienc-y container

33 Strongly recommend

34 Me, myself, and I, perhaps

35 Often said to be the first programmer

36 ordway enerallygay azndsay ikelay isthay

37 Fourth letter, phonetically

**Across**

1 Field with CPSEs

5 WWWWW

8 Word which crossword puzzles have told me means a collection of things

9 Allay any fears

12 Arsenic-Based Life

14 Emulate a clock at 1:08

15 Dalaas

16 Arsenic-Based Life

22 Word that means and also contains a word that means conbrumed

24 [Clue removed for potential spoilers -- even though it's been a month by 
now...]

25 Food with a pocket

26 More than graffiti

27 Arsenic-Based Life

31 Solo at an opern

32 Cuhade

35 Arsenic-Based Life

39 Type of fuega

40 Flips over to the dark side, in Othello

41 Chopper

42 Some poems

[image]

How should your life b(As)e?

Comment: Any reason you've not yet added this puzzle to the [list of FTC puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6353/33080), @stacksfiller ?

Comment: I didn’t add any of them. I thought they autoadded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off @phenomist's answer:

> The incorrect clue letters are all one- or two-letter chemical symbols; the proper letter is always a single letter.
>  In Down-then-Across order, the substitutions are (BI -> N), (GE -> V), (MC -> S), [P -> M], [SB -> E], [ZN -> I], [SE -> U], [AS -> I], [BR -> S], [N -> A], [CU -> S], [GA -> L]
>  Writing the single correct letters in the appropriate locations on a periodic table reveals two crossing A. S. names, "AMIENS" and "SILVIUS". The source of these names is a particular Shakespearean play, and the final answer.
>  [image]

Final answer: How should your life be?

> ***AS* YOU LIKE IT**

Comment: (also note that the order of the initials is given by the strange clue order!)

Answer (score 5):

## Finished crossword, could be more though

> [image]
>  **Exterior theme:** "Arsenic Based Life" are all people with initials A.S.
>  Some clues have been mutated and have had elements replaced. For instance:
>  DOWN
> 2 [Sebiora -> Senora] (probably) (BI -> N)
> 9 Good puzzles [hagee -> have] them (GE -> V)
> 17 [Lamcer -> laser] ray (MC -> S)
> 19 Someone with a bad [tepper -> temper?]
> 21 One of many ways of saying [nonsb -> nonce?]
> 36 ordway enerallygay [azndsay -> aidsay] ikelay isthay (ZN -> I)
> ACROSS
> 1 Field with CPSEs (maybe, this acronym could be something else)
> 15 [Dalaas -> Dalai] (AS -> I)
> 22 Word that means and also contains a word that means [conbrumed -> consumed]
> 31 Solo at an [opern -> opera]
> 32 [Cuhade -> Shade]
> 39 Type of [fuega -> fuel?]
>  Also, weirdly, clue 28D is actually on clue 26D, and the actual clue 28D and 38D are omitted.

Clue explanation for the weirder clues

> 5A - WWWWW -> QED (WWWWW is sometimes used as "Which Was What We/Was Wanted" thanks @ManyPinkHats!)
>  14A - Emulate a clock at 1:08 -> DAB (Dabbing makes your arms point approximately northwest, which is just like an analog clock at 1:08.)
>  22A - Word that means and also contains a word that means consumed -> SATED (SATED contains ATE, both past tense verbs for consumed)
>  24A - LOKI, probably referring to the recent-ish Avengers movie
>  26A - More than graffiti -> MURAL (Murals are larger art pieces on walls than graffiti)
>  40A - Flips over to the dark side, in Othello -> IAGO (Either this is obscure Othello terminology or some Shakespearean reference, but at any rate IAGO is an antagonist in Othello the play)
>  1D - TOAD is not a toad but a mushroom (or rather, a toadstool)
>  2D - ELLA - both mean women?
>  5D - QUA - the Latin phrase sine qua non
>  6D - ERR - "To err is human, to forgive is divine"
>  7D - DED - particularly meme speak or whatever they're calling it these days
>  9D - AHAS - Insights in puzzles are typically called aha moments
>  20D - OKA - A traditional Turkish unit of mass.
>  36D - Ixnay is a commonish Pig Latin word, which un-pig latinfied is NIX.

Comment: Your unsure square should be shifted backwards seven places in the alphabet, I believe.

Comment: 5A is an acronym (juvpu jnf jung jr/jnf jnagrq) which is sometimes used in place of the entry in some claims.